# Use of a Torah scroll

Tags: sefer-torah

May a Torah scroll be used for any purpose other than reading the Torah during a formal Jewish service?  I am thinking in particular about practicing reading the Torah with an actual Torah scroll, but not during a service.

Comment: That sounds like Torah study. What do you suppose people studied from before Guttenburg?

Comment: I have seen pre-barmitzvah boys practicing from a real sefer torah a few times and they weren't leining for a minyan, so I'm pretty sure this is allowed for practice, although a tikkun might be more convenient?

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Worn-out pieces of parchment that today would go in a genizah.

Comment: The Arizal would do שנים מקרא from a real Sefer Torah